# Como não deixar botões de curtir e compartilhar abaixo da imagem do produto?

Tags: css

Não estou conseguindo deixar abaixo do texto de detalhes do meu produto botões de curtir e compartilhar, eles estão sendo deslocados para baixo da foto do produto à esquerda.
Tentei alterar o tamanho da div da imagem do produto, mas não deu certo, vejam a div e sua formatação:

```
<div class="three-fourths">
...
</div>

.three-fourths {
    width: 60.5%;   
    max-width: 700px;   
}
```

A div do texto dos detalhese sua formatação:

```
<div class="one-fourth-pers column-last">
...
</div>

.one-fourth-pers {
    width: 40.5%;
    float:left; 
    /*max-width: 220px;*/
}

.column-last { 
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Um exemplo:

[Detalhes](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/detalhes.php?produto=13&dep=5&sub=21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo que você tem três divs

```
<div class="three-fourths"><!--Imagem--></div>
<div class="one-fourth-pers column-last"><!--Descrição--></div>
<div class="fb-like fb_iframe_widget"><!--FaceBook--></div>
```

Tudo que precisa fazer é mover a div "Facebook" para dentro da div "Detalhes", mais precisamente ao final dela.

```
<div class="three-fourths"><!--Imagem--></div>
<div class="one-fourth-pers column-last">
    <!--Descrição-->
    <div class="fb-like fb_iframe_widget"><!--FaceBook--></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá @TobyMosque, para quem entende do assunto fico tudo muito fácil mesmo, obrigado pela excelente ajuda.